# Chrome element inspector Xpath with @href won't show link text

Tags: html, xml, url, xpath, web-scraping

I am trying to get url from a website's html and here is the Xpath code I tried for StackOverflow's landing page:

```
$x('//*[@id="question-summary-30429261"]/div[2]/h3/a/@href')
```

I think it should return the text after the equal sign in the following statement:

```
href=xxxx
```

but it doesn't.  It just returns null.  I tried Googling this question but no answer came up.  Does someone know the reason why text @href won't show me the link text?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work:

```
$x('//*[@id="question-summary-30429261"]/div[2]/h3/a')[0].getAttribute('href')
```