# xpath to extract link or hrefs

Tags: html, xpath

I am trying to extract the links of similar apps from google playstore from here( using xpath )

```
https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.mojang.minecraftpe
```

Below is the screenshot of the links(marked green) which i wanted to extract
[image]

HTML sample

```
<div class="details"> 
  <a href="/store/apps/details?id=com.imangi.templerun" class="card-click-target"></a>  
  <a title="Temple Run" href="/store/apps/details?id=com.imangi.templerun" class="title">Temple Run 
    <span class="paragraph-end"/> 
  </a>  
  <div>....</div>  
  <div>....</div> 
</div>
```

I have used below xpath in `chrome console` to locate a single link but it doesnt return the href attribute of the  tag. but for other attributes it works(for example "title").

Below xpath doesnt work(extract "href")

```
//*[@id="body-content"]/div/div/div[2]/div[1]//*/a[2]/@href
```

Below xpath works(extract "title")

```
//*[@id="body-content"]/div/div/div[2]/div[1]//*/a[2]/@title
```

[image]

Python code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

HTML of individual tiles on the right of the linked page is in the following form * :

```
<div class="details"> 
  <a href="/store/apps/details?id=com.imangi.templerun" class="card-click-target"></a>  
  <a title="Temple Run" href="/store/apps/details?id=com.imangi.templerun" class="title">Temple Run 
    <span class="paragraph-end"/> 
  </a>  
  <div>....</div>  
  <div>....</div> 
</div>
```

Turned out that *`<a>` element with `class="title"`* uniquely identify your target `<a>` elements in that page. So the XPath can be as simple as :

```
//a[@class="title"]/@href
```

Anyway, the problem you noticed seems to be specific to the Chrome XPath evaluator **. Since you mentioned about Python, simple Python codes proves that the XPath should work just fine :

```py
>>> from urllib2 import urlopen
>>> from lxml import html
>>> req = urlopen('https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.mojang.minecraftpe')
>>> raw = req.read()
>>> root = html.fromstring(raw)
>>> [h for h in root.xpath("//a[@class='title']/@href")]
['/store/apps/details?id=com.imangi.templerun', '/store/apps/details?id=com.lego.superheroes.dccomicsteamup', '/store/apps/details?id=com.turner.freefurall', '/store/apps/details?id=com.mtvn.Nickelodeon.GameOn', '/store/apps/details?id=com.disney.disneycrossyroad_goo', '/store/apps/details?id=com.rovio.angrybirdsstarwars.ads.iap', '/store/apps/details?id=com.rovio.angrybirdstransformers', '/store/apps/details?id=com.disney.dinostampede_goo', '/store/apps/details?id=com.turner.atskisafari', '/store/apps/details?id=com.moose.shopville', '/store/apps/details?id=com.DisneyDigitalBooks.SevenDMineTrain', '/store/apps/details?id=com.turner.copatoon', '/store/apps/details?id=com.turner.wbb2016', '/store/apps/details?id=com.tov.google.ben10Xenodrome', '/store/apps/details?id=com.turner.ggl.gumballrainbowruckus', '/store/apps/details?id=com.lego.starwars.theyodachronicles', '/store/apps/details?id=com.mojang.scrolls']
```

*) Stripped down version. You can take this as an example of providing minimal HTML sample.

**) I can reproduce this problem, that `@href`s are printed as empty string in my Chrome console. The same problem happened to others as well : [Chrome element inspector Xpath with @href won't show link text](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30429402/chrome-element-inspector-xpath-with-href-wont-show-link-text)